# Laravel database design multi-level categories with product details table

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make relashionships between multi-level categories and subcategories, with product details table.

at first i have **categories** table :

```
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | vehicles |
+----+----------+
```

and i have separated table for each category like **category_cars** table :

```
+----+-----------+---------+-------+
| id | parent_id | mileage | motor |
+----+-----------+---------+-------+
| 1  | 1         | 1000    | 1600  |
+----+-----------+---------+-------+
```

and the **products** table :

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | category_id | title |
+----+-------------+-------+
| 1  | 1           | 1000  |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

basically the **category_id** in the **products** table is the **id** of **category_cars**

and when i create a product i set it's **title** in **products** table, then add the other attributes of the proudct to the **category_cars** table like **mileage**, **motor**, **...**

so what if i need to create a sub-category of **vehicles** e.g: **cars**, in this case i have no idea where to create the product.

what i'm trying to achieve is to have multi-level categories, like 9 **static** parent categories and **dynamically** created sub-categories

and a **product attributes** based on which product is this e.g: a car, or a motorcycle.
to be able to have separated data (attribute) for each product type.

there's a default columns that will be globally for each product, like name,price
and each product will need to have it's extra columns depending on it's type.

so the point is to get product this way :

```
product =>
    [
        name = myproduct
        price = 200
        category [
            id = 1
            name = vehicles
        ]
        product details [
            milage = 1000
            motor = 1600
            ...
        ]
        ....
    ]
```

and display all products from a category whether it's main category or sub-category.

i can't figure out how i can make a relashonship between these. the logic itself is so complicated for me.

so how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

this model is named EVA

entity value attribute

i made this befor  and i will share my solution with  u

- category table (id , title , parent_id)
- attributes table (id, title)
- product table (id , title , price , category_id ,.. )
- product_attribute table ( product_id, attr_id , value)

and if u want to make attributes based on category  u will make this table also:

- category_attribute (category_id , attribute_id )

Answer (score 3):

It's a mistake to make separated table for each category like ***category_cars*** table because this means each new category in the future will need new table.

It's more prudent to make self join in categories table and add new column called parent_id in ***categories*** table.

[image]

Comment: Alright, but what about the product attributes? how can i assign different attributes for every main category type? and link it with product?